# How do I add a folder to a program's namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I recently converted a Visual Studio 2006 project up to Visual Studio 2010. The conversion went over fine, but somewhere along the line the namespace got corrupted, and as a result, parts of the codebase are throwing errors (because the objects they're referencing, etc. are no longer being imported).

I can manually locate the folder with the relevant files, but can't seem to reference the file with `using` clauses (or I'm botching `using` entirely). Is there some function in visual studio I can use to import the requisite files directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For physical files you can click the Show All Files button at the top of the solution explorer, then locating the folder, right click and choose Include in Project.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get Resharper installed, it will try to hint you the namespace. if upgrade missed to add some files, then you should add them manually and recompile. i am not sure if you can requisite the files directly

Answer (score 0):

The `using` directive has nothing to do with the folder where the file is located, it is only depending on the name after the "namespace" keyword inside each file.

In some projects people name their namespaces similar to the folder structure but to the c# compiler that is just a coincidence.